# Angular 4 reactive form with array

Tags: angular

**Update**
The code below is fine. There was another function call that reset the `mainForm`'s control causing the error.

I'm trying to bind the `html` template to reactive form. But I'm getting the error below:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'forms -> 0'
```

Below are the files and template I'm using.

**component.ts**

```
mainForm = new FormGroup({
  forms: new FormArray([]),
});

...

buildForm() {
  for ( let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++ ) {
    const fg = new FormGroup({
      active: new FormArray([]),
      price: new FormArray([]),
      moq: new FormArray([]),
    });
    this.items[i].orderBy.forEach(o => {
      (<FormArray>fg.get('active')).push(new FormControl(false));
      (<FormArray>fg.get('price')).push(new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required]));
      (<FormArray>fg.get('moq')).push(new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required]));
    });

    (<FormArray>this.mainForm.get('forms')).push(fg);
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<div [formGroup]="mainForm">
  <div formArrayName="forms">
    <div formGroupName=0>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`formGroupName=0` is just a temporary test. It should look like `<div [formGroupName]="row.$$index">`, might to be consumed by `ngx-datatable`.

But I don't understand why its saying control not found, when its there when I console log the form. The form is also built before the rows are generated.

Comment: can you please replicate this issue in stackblitz

Comment: you can also add `*ngIf` like: `<div *ngIf="mainForm.get('forms').at(0)" formGroupName=0>`

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
<div [formGroup]="mainForm">
  <div formArrayName="forms">
    <div *ngFor="let form of mainForm.controls['forms'].controls; let i = index", [formGroupName]="i">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: <div [formGroupName]="0">